# After many iterations, VBA call to Acrobat API starts returning "The remote procedure call failed"

Tags: javascript, vba, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of PDFs and, for each one, flatten it using the Acrobat API to access the PDF's JS Object.  Because VBA doesn't have a code-accessible stack trace, I have a wrapper class `AcroExchWrapper` that wraps each Acrobat API function to identify the function if it fails, e.g.

```
Public Sub ClosePDF()

On Error GoTo errHandler
'AcroDoc is created with CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
AcroDoc.Close
Exit Sub

errHandler:
Err.Raise Err.Number, "AcroExchWrapper.ClosePDF (" & Err.source & ")", Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext

End Sub
```

Each PDF is flattened using the following code:

```
Private Function flattenPDF(pdfPath As String, savePath As String, deleteOld As Boolean) As String

Dim pageCount As Integer
Dim jso As Object
Dim saveResult As Long
Dim openResult As Long
Dim creatingApp As String


On Error GoTo errHandler

creatingApp = ""
If deleteOld Then
    If fso.FileExists(savePath) Then
        fso.DeleteFile savePath
    End If
End If
acroExch.ClosePDF
openResult = acroExch.OpenPDF(pdfPath)
If openResult = 0 Then
    Err.Raise "-1", "Flattener.flattenPDF", "unable to open PDF"
End If
DoEvents
Set jso = acroExch.GetJSObject
DoEvents
If jso Is Nothing Then
    Err.Raise "-1", "Flattener.flattenPDF", "unable to get JS object"
Else    
    pageCount = acroExch.GetNumPages
    creatingApp = acroExch.GetInfo("Creator")    
    If pageCount <> -1 Then
        flattenPages jso, 0, pageCount - 1
    Else
        flattenPages jso
    End If
    DoEvents
    saveResult = acroExch.SavePDF(savePath)
    If saveResult = 0 Then
        Err.Raise "-1", "Flattener.flattenPDF", "unable to save PDF"
    End If
    acroExch.ClosePDF
    If pdfPath <> savePath Then
        loggerObj.addEntry pdfPath, savePath, "flattened", creatingApp
    End If
End If
flattenPDF = savePath
Exit Function

errHandler:

loggerObj.addErrorEntryFromErrorObj pdfPath, "", "flattenPDF", Err, creatingApp
flattenPDF = ""

End Function

'wrapper for jso.flattenPages to allow for stack trace
Private Sub flattenPages(jso As Object, Optional startPage As Long = -1, Optional endPage As Long = -1)

On Error GoTo errHandler
If startPage = -1 Then
    jso.flattenPages
Else
    jso.flattenPages startPage, endPage
End If
Exit Sub

errHandler:
Err.Raise Err.Number, "flattenPages (" & Err.source & ")", Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext

End Sub
```

After going through several thousand files--the number is different each time I run the script--`flattenPages()` raises the following error:

```
Automation error
The remote procedure call failed.
```

After that, for all remaining files, when `flattenPDF()` runs, the first call to `acroExch.ClosePDF()` raises this error:

```
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on why these errors occur when using Acrobat API, whether with the Javascript API (`jso.flattenPages()`) or the IAC API (`PDDoc.Close()`).  More mysterious is that the application runs fine until it gets to some varying number of files and only then starts throwing these exceptions.

EDIT: I added the following function to `AcroExchWrapper` to reset Acrobat, to be performed every 100 files:

```
Public Sub Reset()

ClosePDF
AcroApp.Exit
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcroDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

Exit Sub
```

However, the same exceptions are still being thrown.  This seems to be occurring once 1500-2500 files have been processed.

Comment: Acrobat is a desktop application and really wasn't engineered to handle that kind of a load. There are server tools that will provide better performance. If you absolutely must use the Acrobat client, modify your application to quit Acrobat every hundred files or so, and then start it back up before proceeding.

Comment: I don't have any server access, so I have to do everything client-side.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: @joelgeraci, I added a quit/restart function, but that didn't solve the problem (see edit).

Comment: Well... it was worth a try. I just don't think you're going to be able to process that kind of volume with Acrobat. It just wasn't engineered for that use case. While I did say server tools were available, I should have said library tools are available. There are several library tools that will flatten PDF and can be run on the client. I'd start exploring those as options.